# Batch+Oracle, disable response but still get execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, time

I have a batch file running some sql for me through sqlplus.
The command goes as follows :

```
sqlplus user/password@sid @file.sql param1 param2 ... >> LOG.txt
```

By browsing the internet I did find out that it was possible to get time by adding those lines to the sql file :

```
SET TIMING ON
...sql operation...
SET TIMING OFF
```

This gives me a really nice result in the log file, since now it looks like this:

```
SQL*PLUS INFORMATION
COPYRIGHT
INFORMATION ABOUT THE CONNECTION
OLD/NEW STATEMENT
RESULTS
ROWS SELECTED
EXECUTION TIME
DISCONNECT MESSAGE
```

I really do like the output of this, but the RESULTS are to much. Often I want to test the execution time of long queries, but passing through the results really is a waste of bandwith. It also makes my log file huge and impractical, I would rather have a small log with all the other information.

I tried adding other headers such as :

```
TERMOUT
SPOOL
```

But the first one remove all output, including the time and the old/new statement, and the second one just copies the results into an other file without changing anything to my log file.

I was thinking to wrap my request in an PLSQL block, but then I would no be able to use the TIME header anymore right ?

Anyway, if you guys know of a header/other component that would resolve my problem, feel free to share !

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use SQLPLUS bind variables in your script to store a start time and calculate an execution time of the query:

```
var start_time varchar2;

exec :start_time := to_char( current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.SSSSS');

/* Long runing query */
BEGIN
 DBMS_LOCK.sleep(5);
END;
/

SELECT current_timestamp - to_timestamp( :start_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.SSSSS' ) 
       As total_ececution_time
from dual;
```

---

A result is:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


TOTAL_ECECUTION_TIM
-------------------
+00 00:00:05.471000
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much sir. Worked perfectly for me !